# why is my array updated even when I don't choose to update it

Tags: java

I'm a little confused as to why this is happening. I'm sorry if the answer is obvious, I'm still quite new at Java. 
 
So I thought I had set up my `int[] returning` so that it only updates when I choose it to update but for some reason it updates every single time that `temp[]` changes. Here's the code. Please feel free to ask certain things that are unclear so that I can help you help me.

```
 public int[] generateTable(Graph g, int index, int cap, int[] current, int[] edges, int count) {
         int truthAmount = 0;   
         int result = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
         int[] temp = new int[count];
         int k = 0;
         int[] returning = new int[count];
         for(int i = 0; i < Math.pow(2, count); i++){
            for(int j = count-1; j>=0; j--){
               int num = (i/(int) Math.pow(2, j))%2;
               temp[k] = num;
               if(temp[k] == 0)
                  truthAmount++;
               k++;

            }
            if(truthAmount >= cap){
               result = FFAHelper(g, temp, edges);
               if(result < min){
                  min = result;
                  returning = temp;
               }
            }
            k = 0;
            truthAmount = 0;
         }

         return returning;
      }
```

What it's basically doing is generating a binary table where a 0 represents true and 1 represents false. It'll only go on to perform the FFAHelper method if the count of trues is at least the amount of the cap (this is all for a graph/edge class, I know it's not a traditional set up for a graph/edge class but I had to agree to doing it like this) So basically it won't go on to FFAHelper without the truthAmount being at least the amount of edges. 
Again, the problem is that it'll update `returning` even when it doesn't go through the if condition. 
Thanks guys for your help and time!

Comment: `returning = temp.clone();` use this instead of `returning = temp`

Comment: @Pratik make this an answer and add a little explanation, you'll get my +1 and and probably an accept by Ceelos

Comment: Yes, your answer actually worked for him. Make it an answer so he could approve it.

Comment: I have added my answer now.. Thanks

Comment: hey @jlordo ya thanks for your +1 and he accepted my answer too. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`returning = temp.clone();` use this instead of `returning = temp`. 
If you use `returning = temp` then `temp` reference value gets assigned to `returning`.

Hence every time when you update temp it will also update returning.

For this case if you use `clone` method. Then it will ***create a copy of temp and assign to returning***.
so even if you update `temp` it won't update the `returning` because reference values for temp and returning are different.

Comment: Thank you so much Pratrik! 
That was the last part I needed to fix for my project.

Answer (score 4):

```
returning = temp;
```

Basically when you do this both returning and temp reference the same object

Comment: ahhhhhhh that's right because arrays are objects! I totally forgot about this. Learned it when I took my semantics class.

Answer (score 2):

When you do

```
returning= temp
```

You are saying equate the whole returning array.I.e. Make returning temp in the same memory location

What you should do is

```
returning= temp.clone()
```

Equate one number to another. So that returning and temp occupy different memory space

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want returning array to change, then you should clone the temp and assign the cloned value to returning array.

Here in this case, temp.clone() would work as you only have primitive type of array.
If you have complex objects in the array, then you should take care of cloning each and every object inside array, as temp.clone() (default implementation) would not do a true deep copy.